# Cant boot to windows 10 after replacing the motherboard

Tags: windows-10, boot

My past motherboard is Gigabyte P75-D3 with windows 10. Now I have bought a new B550 Aorus motherboard. When I install the SSD with this windows 10 I get the following message while booting up :

[image]

However, when I install back again the SSD to the old motherboard the windows work well. I don't need to format the SSD as it contains crucial data for my work and I don't have any additional Hard drive for backup. So what to do in this case? Can this problem be solved?

Comment: You need to proceed with the Repair. It should keep data but you cannot be 100% certain. Get a USB drive from your local Office Store, back up your data and proceed with the Repair.

Comment: @John is the problem is occurring because the new motherboard is damaged? Do I return it?

Comment: The motherboard will have a new CPU and BIOS. That could be the problem. You can ask the supplier if you should return it. My guess is that the board is likely OK and just not compatible with your current install which is why I suggest backing it up and proceeding with the repair.

Comment: Your next problem may be that Windows is no longer authorised. You might have to ring Microsoft to try persuade them it is not a 'new computer' needing a new OS purchase.

Comment: @Tetsujin If his license was linked to his Microsoft account, he should be able to just enter his product key. (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/reactivating-windows-10-after-a-hardware-change-2c0e962a-f04c-145b-6ead-fb3fc72b6665)

Comment: @jitter - License key has been used once. This is a "new computer" as far as the license is concerned. It may take a human to override that decision. Windows licenses are not 'per human', they're 'per computer'..

Comment: thanks all for the help

Comment: You can sysprep the old installation first, then replace the motherboard, no need to reinstall the OS>>>>https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-hardware-winpc/motherboard-upgrade-with-windows-10/a41d5ab4-3bf7-4b07-8b07-7a1c5627b3c9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I worked as IT Support in a school and this is a pretty common problem. The thing is, you can't just replace your motherboard and expect your OS (Windows) to work like nothing ever happened.

Different motherboard (which ultimately means different processor, chipsets, onboard graphic cards, etc) require different drivers from those currently installed on your OS. Sometimes, the OS boots up just fine, if the new motherboard belongs to the same brand, but in your case, it has different brand. In my experience, "Repair" won't help. You have to choice but reinstall.

Detailed steps:

- Assemble the old motherboard back and turn on your PC.
- Create new partition on it and name it drive D (or whatever alphabet), if you haven't already.
- Use partition tool/software to tweak drive C and drive D's size if necesssary.
- Copy all your documents/non programs to drive D.
- Perform a google search and download a new copy Windows 10 Disc Image (ISO).
- Burn it to USB flash drive with the provided software. Or any other bootable ISO burner. Please notice that you can't just copy the files into the USB flash drive.
- Shut down. Replace the motherboard.
- Enter BIOS and make your PC boot to USB flash drive.
- Delete all partition except drive D during Windows 10 installation. Create new partition on the empty space and install Windows there.

Answer (score 0):

Rezising the partition may work, but in case of error (human or technical) you rist your data.
If any device contents crucial data for your work you should backup it to another device. Every Hardware WILL fail! Critical DATA is probably less than 64 GB. So a USB pen Drive for 10 $$ may be the answer. You will need a second one, to repair the Windows. 8 Gig is enough.

Old rule in IT.
No Backup No Mercy !!

Greetings from Germany

Comment: Thank you very much for the help .